# What does "asking all the questions" mean in football (soccer)?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "asking all the questions" mean in football (soccer)?
(This sentence is taken from [this sports article](https://amp.sportsmole.co.uk/football/man-utd/live-commentary/live-commentary-man-city-vs-man-utd_322886.html?__twitter_impression=true))

> Man City the side **asking all the questions** as we enter the second of five added-on minutes at the Etihad Stadium. The Citizens will wonder quite how they trail in this contest, but credit must go to United for stepping things up.

Comment: The side "asking all the questions" is the side with some advantage in a contest. This is a general usage phrase, not specific to sports.

Comment: You should cite the source for all quotations.

Answer (score 1):

It is a metaphor.  Now I suppose you were following the match.

What were city doing?

How could a team "ask a question" of the other team?

What sort of "questions" could a team ask?

When someone asks a question you have to answer it. What would an "answer" be on the football pitch?

---

You know that City were playing better than United at this point. They were making repeated attacks.  Could an attack "ask a question"?

A team can "ask a question" by playing well and forcing the opponents to respond.

The "questions" are "Can you defend against us on the wing" "Can you save goals?" and so on

It means that City were playing better than United, and forcing United to respond defensively.

Comment: So, "ask a question" here mean to mount an attack. Is that right?